# Facebook login with Firebase. Can't find OAuth redirect URI

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following the manual provided by Firebase. However, there is an early step I cannot seem to do. The manual tells me to

[image]

Where can I find this setting on Facebook?

[image]

From other manual it should be just below client token, but it isnt. I highly appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have just created your Facebook app, then you have to first add the "Facebook Login" *Product*.
You can do so by clicking on the `+ Add Product` link under the `PRODUCTS` section on the left side of the page and by choosing `Facebook Login` in the resulting page.

Once you've added this *Product* you can find the settings in the following page

https://developers.facebook.com/sa/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/fb-login/

Please replace `YOUR_APP_ID` with your real App ID, which is a string like `078717227531318`.